# How to create border design like in images below and animate them

Tags: modeling, animation

[image][image]Can anyone tell me how to create those designs over a book or album

And how to animate them like originated on left and end on right or from center to edges or top to bottom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using Curves, Bezier or Path curves. Make the curves into the pattern that you want then go into the Bevel option on the side properties and Select "Profile" option, then increase the depth according to your needs. You can animate them too.
[image]

Comment: Ok, i will try using this basic information and will come to you with result or with problem to get help
So please bare with me for sometime